# Model measurement and error in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, octave

I'd like to try the SciPy suite instead of Octave for doing the statistics in my lab experiments. Most of my questions were answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12343271/653152), there is just another thing left:

I usually have an error attached to the measurements, in Octave I just did the following:

```
R.val = 10;
R.err = 0.1;

U.val = 4;
U.err = 0.1;
```

And then I would calculate `I` with it like so:

```
I.val = U.val / R.val;
I.err = sqrt(
    (1 / R.val * U.err)^2
    + (U.val / R.val^2 * R.err)^2
);
```

When I had a bunch of measurements, I usually used a structure array, like this:

```
R(0).val = 1;
R(0).err = 0.1;
…
R(15).val = 100;
R(15).err = 9;
```

Then I could do `R(0).val` or directly access all of them using `R.val` and I had a column vector with all the values, for `mean(R.val)` for instance.

How could I represent this using SciPy/NumPy/Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest is indeed to use NumPy [structured arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html), that give you the possibility to define arrays of homogeneous elements (a record) composed of other homogeneous elements (fields).

For example, you could define

```
R = np.empty(15, dtype=[('val',float),('err',float)])
```

and then fill the corresponding columns:

```
R['val'] = ...
R['err'] = ...
```

Alternatively, you could define the array at once if you have your `val` and `err` in two lists:

```
R = np.array(zip(val_list, err_list), dtype=[('val',float),('err',float)])
```

In both cases, you can access individual elements by indices, like `R[0]` (which would give you a specific object, a `np.void`, that still gives you the possibility to access the fields separately), or by slices `R[1:-1]`...

With your example, you could do:

```
I = np.empty_like(R)
I['val'] = U['val'] / R['val']
I['err'] = np.sqrt((1 / R['val'] * U['err'])**2 + (U['val'] / R['val']**2 * R['err'])**2)
```

You could also use *record array*, which are basic structured array with the `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` methods overloaded in such way that you can access the fields as attributes (like in `R.val`) as well as indices (like the standard `R['val']`). Of course, as these basic methods are overloaded, record arrays are not as efficient as structured arrays.

Comment: This seems to be the exact thing I am looking for. Thanks!

Comment: There is a program that does exactly this and does it automatically and transparently: [uncertainties](http://pythonhosted.org/uncertainties/index.html). (Disclaimer: I'm the author!)

Answer (score 5):

This kind of error propagation is exactly what the [uncertainties](http://pythonhosted.org/uncertainties/index.html) Python package does. It does so *transparently* and by correctly handling *correlations*:

```
from uncertainties import ufloat

R = ufloat(10, 0.1)
U = ufloat(4, 0.1)
I = U/R

print I
```

prints `0.4+/-0.0107703296143`, after automatically determining and calculating the error formula that you typed manually in your example. Also, `I.n` and `I.s` are respectively the nominal value (your `val`) and the standard deviation (your `err`).

Arrays holding numbers with uncertainties can also be used (http://pythonhosted.org/uncertainties/numpy_guide.html).

(Disclaimer: I'm the author of this package.)

Comment: :Hello, I am searching about errors and I just saw your package.I want to ask something by the way.For example, I am using a numpy function.Do I know the result of this function what error has?Or do I have to manually define it?Is there anywhere in the numpy source code any information about this?Thank you

Comment: `uncertainties` has support for NumPy through the `uncertainties.unumpy` package. It allows you to do things like `sin(array_with_uncertainties)`.

Comment: :Thanks for the reply and for building this package!Because I didn't quite understand ,I want to ask you.I know that if I supply the error, using uncertainties it will propagate the error.But, If for example I use a numpy function,let's say the `np.interp`, is there any way either using numpy either using uncertainties to know the error that the result of calling this function has?What kind of errors numpy functions have to their results?I hope it is clear.Thanks!

Comment: The closest thing to this is `uncertainties.wrap()` (https://pythonhosted.org/uncertainties/user_guide.html#making-custom-functions-accept-numbers-with-uncertainties): it creates an uncertainty-aware function from a regular function. Now, it is not meant to generally be used with arrays, so your mileage may vary. Maybe another useful function would be the internal `unumpy.func_with_deriv_to_uncert_func()`. The `uncertainties` module could use some user-centric wrapper for functions on Numpy array. Note: this discussion should be somewhere else than as a string of comments here!

Comment: :Ok, thanks!(I didn't know where else to start it :)

Comment: The official uncertainties website has my contact information!

Answer (score 1):

For just one measurement probably simple [namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) would suffice.

And instead of structure arrays you can use [numpy's record arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html). Seems to be little bit more mouthful though.

Also [google cache of NumPy for Matlab Users](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3ascipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users&sugexp=chrome,mod=11&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) (direct link doesn't work for me atm) can help with some counterparts of basic operations.

Comment: With the answer by Pierre GM, I now see that your answer is the right direction. I just did not see that from the documentation right away, sorry.

Comment: @queueoverflow: Yeah should've included an example! Even the barest one. He illustrated exactly record arrays.

Answer (score 0):

There is a package for representing quantities along with uncertainties in Python. It is called [quantities](http://packages.python.org/quantities/user/tutorial.html) ! (also [on PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/quantities)).

Comment: That looks interesting. I'll have to see how well it plays with regular NumPy.

Comment: It should be quite OK. The dev' of this package helped improve the creation of subclasses of `ndarray`s.

Comment: The [uncertainties](http://pythonhosted.org/uncertainties/index.html) package has the advantage over quantities of correctly handling correlations between variables. For example: x+x is incorrectly calculated by the quantities package. (Disclaimer: I am the author of uncertainties.)